# Saving data from worker into columns in database (rails, resque)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I have a simple worker that performs methods on some text and stores them in variables. How can I saved this data into the allocated columns?

Controller:

```
def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)
    if @blog.save
        Resque.enqueue(Counter, Blog.extract_text)
        redirect_to backend_blogs_path, notice: "Success!"
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```

Model:

```
 def self.extract_text
     Blog.last.text
 end
```

Worker:

```
class Counter

    @queue = :count

    def self.perform(*args)
       @wordcount = args.count
       @@charactercount = args.size
       @whitespacecount = args.count(" ")
    end

end
```

As you can see I need to store the data from these three variables into the columns in the database.

```
  create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "text"
    t.string "image"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.boolean "active"
    t.integer "whitespacecount"
    t.integer "charactercount"
    t.integer "wordcount"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_blogs_on_slug", unique: true
  end
```

Do I need to pass them back into the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the text directly to the worker just pass the pass the id of the blog:

```
# in your controller
def create
  @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)
  if @blog.save
    Resque.enqueue(Counter, @blog.id)
    redirect_to backend_blogs_path, notice: "Success!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Then in your worker, load the blog, analyze it and write the database back:

```
# in the worker
class Counter
  @queue = :count

  def self.perform(blog_id)
    blog = Blog.find(blog_id)

    blog.update(
      wordcount:       blog.text.split(' ').count,
      charactercount:  blog.text.size,
      whitespacecount: blog.text.count(' ')
    )
  end
end
```

Comment: That is so interesting that you are allowed to update the attributes from the worker.

Comment: Normally it can be done in the controller? Could you explain this?